# Flash - Mouse Event Handling (Make symbol transparent to mouse)

Tags: flash, mouse, bitmap, sprite, transparent

I have a flash that has a background symbol that responds to CLICK event.
On top of that symbol I have a sprite that contains a Bitmap with transparent pixels.
Both of them are added to the stage, so they are not related directly.

I want clicks on the transparent pixels on the sprite to go straight through to the background.

I have read about mouseEnabled / mouseChildren but have not been able to make these work.
The symbol ignores the mouse events when I use them, but does not pass it along as if its transparent.

Is this possible to do with flash? Or will I have to re-route mouse events?

Thanks

Comment: Either setting the background Sprite's mouseChildren property to false, or setting each child's mouseEnabled property false should do the trick. Maybe The background click event is set up incorrectly? Post up some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener on your Bitmap (no need to wrap your Bitmap inside a Sprite) to listen for the MouseEvent.CLICK event.

Then, in your click handler function, just use getPixel32 to get the alpha of the clicked pixel :

```
var alpha:String = ( yourBitmap.BitmapData.getPixel32( e.localX, e.localY ) >> 24 & 0xFF).toString(16);
if( alpha == "0" )
    // Trigger your symbol click handler here
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.

Perhaps I didn't explain myself well enough. What I mean is that I have 2 sprites connected to the stage.

1) A background that fills the entire stage.

2) A sprite that is attached to the stage as well.

Now, both symbols (bg/sprite) respond to 'click'.

I want transparent pixels to basically get ignored and pass the click right through to the background. Thanks again

Comment: Since you use the term "symbols", I suppose they are created in Flash IDE and not programmatically, right? If it's the case, I don't see how to use this method, since I don't know how to access the Bitmap object inside the symbol (I'm not quite used to work with Flash and its librairy =/) By the way, are you using AS2 or AS3?

Comment: We're using AS3. Actually its a mix, we're using Flash to export our symbols and Flex Builder to program in.

If you're interested in what was actually wrong I wrote it below,
My fix was to make the PlayerSprites a child of the background.
This way if a mouse event is ignored by a player sprite symbol, the background is still within the event route and gets processed.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem is.

My scene is built like this:

stage -> container #1 -> container #2 -> PlayerSprites
      -> Background

Marking the player sprites as mouseEnabled = false / mouseChildren = false does in fact disable the mouse.

How ever by that time, the mouse event is in container #2, Because of this it will not reach the background symbol in a 'transparent' manner.